# add <div> after <h3> tag opan and close </div> before </h3> tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html

I want to wrap text with div, can someone help how can I do this. I can't change my html structure therefore i need to use jquery.

here is my html code

```
<div>
<h3>Title 1</h3>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
<br />
<br />
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

<h3>Title 1</h3>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
<br />
<br />
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</div>
```

here is js

```
$('h3').each(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('h3')
        .wrapAll('<div>').parent().add(this)
        .wrapAll('<li>').parent().appendTo(h3);
});
```

[here is jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/SjDe2/38/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to keep `br`?

Comment: no, I dont need it, but i can't change html

Comment: Is that what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/SjDe2/44/

Comment: there is no div after h3 tag, check my original html structure. My output will be same as u provided.

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this

```
$('div').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).wrap('<div></div>');
```

This will select all the plain text and wrap it with div elements

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SjDe2/40/)

**Edit**

This will do the trick,

```
$('div').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).wrap('<div class="temp"></div>');

$("h3").each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil("h3").wrapAll("<div class='wraper'></div>");
});

$(".temp").contents().unwrap();
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SjDe2/46/)

Comment: Thanks for ur replay, i want to create html structure like this http://jsfiddle.net/SjDe2/43/